# Button alignment in a GridLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

My layout code and its graphical representation is as shown below:

This is how it looks:

[image: This is how it looks:]

When I try to put in button inside in the grid layout, it doesn't show. I tried setting row count and column count to 2, but it doesn't seem to work.

I want to make the layout look something like this :

[image: I want to make the layout look something this:]

This is what my xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/goButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="goClick"
        android:padding="50dp"
        android:text="GO!"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorActivatedHighlight"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="30s"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/textColorLinkInverse"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="0/0"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="3 + 7 = ?"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.49"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="474dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have put a button their but its not visible:

[image: I have put a button their but its not visible:]

Thank You For the Answer

Comment: please post you layout file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what does the actual xml file look like? That would be more helpful, but while not seeing your xml file make sure all the buttons are inside of the grid layout tags. Set the grid layout width and heights to match parent if you would like to keep everything even set the column count and row count to 2 then on your buttons you have to set layout_columnweight and layout_rowweight to 1 on every button so they are only taking up 1 section on the grid.Try starting with that, like I said though if you post your xml file ill be able to tell you exactly whats wrong

it should look something like this

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="//schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="//schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="2">
    <Button
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="#color you want"
        android:textSize="size you want"
        android:text="text you want" />
    <Button
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="#color you want"
        android:textSize="size you want"
        android:text="text you want" />
    <Button
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="#color you want"
        android:textSize="size you want"
        android:text="text you want" />
    <Button
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="#color you want"
        android:textSize="size you want"
        android:text="text you want" />
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `android:gravity=""` attribute, see below code it think it's like what you want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:columnCount="2">

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:text="Title1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="Title2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Title3" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:text="Title4" />

 </GridLayout>
```